# Why weren't Ron and Hermione allowed to enter the Three Broomsticks?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* (film), why were Ron and Hermione kept from entering the Three Broomsticks by the shrunken heads for being underage, when Hogwarts students went in there all the time?

Comment: Because the films are nonsense? ;-)

Comment: Doesn't one of the heads explicitly mention that it's like adults only that day? EDIT: ffs @rand al'thor :D

Comment: @MacCooper Yup, and ninja'd by 15 seconds!

Comment: Shrunken heads? Wtf, movies? I'm becoming increasingly glad I've only seen about half the movies and have forgotten most of what I've seen.

Comment: The third movie is worst by far. Bald werewolf, who has piano in Shrieking Shack for some reason. All these shrunken heads. They used different actors when they traveled to past. It's just a mess.

Comment: @zikato they used different actors for the time travel?

Comment: @randal'thor +1 on the films throwing continuity out of the window. Most of the time Harrys glasses didn't even have lenses. Warner Brothers, dressing stars in medially unnecessary glasses before it was cool.

Comment: @MacCooper Yes, since they were kids, it makes sense that they would use different actors than the adult stars. I don't know what Zikato's complaint really is, but it's certainly unfounded.

Comment: @tylerH I thought he meant when Harry and Hermione fo back in time in the third film.

Comment: @MacCooper Hm, I'm pretty sure Emma Watson and Dan Radcliffe were still the actors during those scenes.

Comment: @tylerH  yh me too

Comment: @randal'thor Can you post your first comment as an answer so we can close every other question asking about why something dumb happens in the movies as a duplicate?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I'm [working](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/121780/31394) on [that](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121764/why-are-lilys-eyes-green-and-not-blue-like-harrys/121768#121768)!

Answer (score 50):

What the "shrunken head" actually says in the film is (emphasis mine):

> "I say! No underage wizards allowed in **today**! Shut the damn door!"

So it was only on that particular day, or that particular time, that underage wizards weren't allowed in the Three Broomsticks, and there's no contradiction with the fact that Hogwarts students go in there all the time on other days.

As for the *reason*, it probably had to do with **the meeting going on in there** between the Minister for Magic and some of the teachers. While they were discussing the ins and outs of the case of the (supposed) mass murderer Sirius Black, they wouldn't want random kids overhearing their conversation. Especially one Mr Harry Potter, although as things turned out, their precautions were rather useless on that score...

<sub>*(It should be noted that this whole "shrunken heads" business is pointless nonsense made up for the films, and has no basis in canon.)*</sub>

Comment: Potter wasn't supposed to be in town anyway so the precaution wouldn't have been specifically about him. +1 to the films playing fast and loose with the text sometimes