# Why did the Death Eaters have torches at the Quidditch World Cup?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters

In the fourth movie of Harry Potter, when the Death Eaters were at the Quidditch World Cup, why did they have torches? I don't get why they had torches if they had wands that could do the same thing.

Comment: They are marshmallows, to make giant s'mores

Comment: lol, never though of it that way :D

Comment: yup, sure and they use the wands as sticks to put cotton candy on ;)

Comment: Torches are essential for mob lynching. And pitchforks! ;)

Comment: If their wands are being used as torches then how are they supposed to use other spells if they need to attack/defend themselves. We never see a wand cast 2 spells at once, so using it as a torch is just wasting the most versatile weapon you have on a simple spell, preventing you from casting others

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Because the films are nonsense.

In this scene in the films, the Death Eaters were deliberately made to look like the [Ku Klux Klan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ku_Klux_Klan):

[image]

There is nothing in the book about them wearing pointy hats or carrying big flaming sticks. These elements of the Death Eater parade were added to the film so that viewers could more easily and visually identify them with *real-life* evil cults.

Comment: It comes to conclusion that films are full of rubish

Comment: This seems to be a theme...I wonder why...

Comment: Films can never bring whole book to screen, not matter how well film was made. It will always skip some parts of a book, noone wants to watch move for 6 or 8 hours

Comment: @VanjaVasiljevic I'm working on a [feature-request](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121354/why-werent-ron-and-hermione-allowed-to-enter-the-three-broomsticks/121355#comment298512_121354) here ;-)

Comment: Don't lots of wizards wear pointy hats?

Comment: I think the reasoning in this answer gives a fairly good reason for them to be dressed this way, backed up by @Vanja Vasiljevic's comment on film timing. I'm started to feel the films are getting too harsh a reputation here. They need to get the message across that they're scary cult-like people in a very limited time. It's what adaptation is about.

Comment: @ThruGog True, this isn't a major problem with the films. I just like to gripe about them in general :-)

Comment: @rand al'thor - Yeah, they have their issues, and I was against them for years as a book lover since the beginning, but now I wonder how else people really want it done. A TV series one day to fit everything in? Will be interesting certainly. They as films just cannot be made longer, and they have a HELL of a cast.

Comment: Maybe include the JKR comments (in the DVD extras or something) where she says the Death Eaters were racist/prejudiced and so she thought it was neat that the film had them look like the kkk.

Comment: @RedCaio I just had a quick search and couldn't find any such comments. If you link me to a source, I'll happily add it in :-)

Comment: I'm very glad they changed that before the next movie! :)

Comment: Rand al'Thor ,Why are the films nonsense?